# Bundling Failed and showed the following message

Tags: react-native

bundling failed: Error: While resolving module `react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen`, the Haste package `react-native` was found. However the module `Libraries/NewAppScreen` could not be found within the package. Indeed, none of these files exist:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what resolved the whole error for me @Nijat Alijev thanks for pointing out newappscreen.

> it happens that i was importing Colors from

```
 react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen. Like this => import { Colors }from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
```

So what resolve the error for me was simply removing #react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen#
Then npm install. it works like magic no need to killall -9 node and all that

Answer (score 1):

Re-install react-native or remove newappscreen files in app.js.

for example App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>
        Test
      </Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, dear, I've resolved it actually I was using color style and mistakenly 'Color' wrote and it was imported from NewsAppScreen and that was the error